# Laravel Left join add where clause to right table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

If I add a where clause to a left join, that this where clause is working on the right table, I only get those results frome left table that can match the right table.

```
$notifications = \DB::table('notifications')
            ->select(\DB::raw("notifications.uuid ,images.local_path as title_image" ))
            ->leftJoin('images','images.owner_uuid', '=' ,'notifications.uuid')
where('images.relation','=','notification_title') ;
```

How can I add this where clause to the left join, that does not make this problem?

```
where('images.relation','=','notification_title') ;
```

Comment: add the `where` clause before `leftJoin`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

in left join all the where clauses that are going to act on the right table must be added to the JOIN statement itself. use this code

```
$notifications = \DB::table('notifications')
            ->select(\DB::raw("notifications.uuid , images.local_path as title_image" ))
            ->leftJoin('images',function ($join) {
                $join->on('images.owner_uuid', '=' , 'notifications.uuid') ;
                $join->where('images.relation','=','notification_title') ;
            });
```